# Stop auto scroll after jQuery fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fade

I have this fade slider:

https://eventpay.co.il/test.html

The background image of the div "header_photo" changes every 7 seconds to other image.
The problem is when you scroll down to read the text, then the page is auto-scrolled up to the slider.
I want to stop this.
I tried some ideas and it's doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: use fadeTo and fadeIn instead

Answer (score 1):

Use fadeTo instead so the div doesn't disappear and reappear causing the scrolling behavior you described.

```
$('#header_photo').fadeTo(900,0.1,function() {
    $('#header_photo').css({
        'background-image' : "url('" + backgrounds[currentBackground] + "')"
    });
    $('#header_photo').fadeTo(900, 1.0);
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/dufadi/1/

Comment: You right, I make the changes in the wrong file..
Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to hear it. I like these kind of problems. ;) Would you mind kindly accepting my solution?